Are there orthogonality relations for the Burnside ring / table of marks known?
I would like to ask the following.

Are there orthogonality relations for the Burnside ring / table of marks known?

There are formulæ known for idempotent elements, but I am searching for something different (yet related). For example, in the case of Brauer characters, we have the formula
$$\Phi^\text{tr}D^{-1}\overline{\Pi} = \text{Id}_{n\times n},$$
and I am searching for something similar, and also in terms of matrices. More precisely:
Let $G$ be a finite group, let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic $p$ dividing $|G|$.
In the article "The Green ring of a finite group",
the authors Benson and Parker define the inner product $(M,N) := \dim_k(\operatorname{Hom}_{kG}(M,N))$ on the basis elements of the Green ring $A(G)$.
It is shown that there exists a set of elements $\hat{M}\in A(G)$ which are
dual to the basis elements with respect to the bilinear form. This means that
if $M$ and $L$ are indecomposable, then $(L, \hat{M}) = \delta_{LM}$. These dual elements
may be constructed as follows: if $M$ is indecomposable and non-projective,
we let $0 \rightarrow N \rightarrow E \rightarrow M \rightarrow 0$ be the Auslander–Reiten sequence terminating at $M$ and put $\hat{M}= M + N - E$. If M is indecomposable projective we put $\hat{M} = M - \operatorname{Rad}(M)$.
This statement of the existence and identification of dual
elements can be regarded in itself as a statement about orthogonality
relations, just as the usual Brauer orthogonality relations can be taken to be
a statement involving duality with respect to the bilinear form induced by
$( , )$ on the Grothendieck ring of $kG$-modules.
But one can say more: writing $\Phi$ for the Brauer projective table, $\Pi$ for the Brauer character table and setting $D:=\operatorname{diag}(|C_G(g_1)|, \dotsc, |C_G(g_n)|)$ where {g_1, \dotsc , g_n} is a set of representatives of the $p^\prime$-classes of $G$, then the orthogonality relations can be written as
$$\Phi^\text{tr}D^{-1}\overline{\Pi} = \text{Id}_{n\times n}.\tag{$*$}\label{478057_star}$$
Considering modules with cyclic vertices more closely, Benson and Parker also express their relations in terms of certain character tables. They form two square tables with columns indexed by the species of $A(G, CYC)$ and with rows indexed by the indecomposable $kG$-modules with cyclic vertex and obtain a formula which has similarities with \eqref{478057_star}.

Are there orthogonality relations for the Burnside ring / table of marks known which are of similar fashion (such that we do not only have something like $M\cdot M^{-1}=\text{Id}$) but involving rows or columns and dual elements, species, etc.?


@LSpice Yes, thanks, I have edited the question.

I'm happy to see that someone is reading my old paper with Richard Parker, who sadly and unexpectedly died recently. If you liked that paper, maybe you'd also like (am I beginning to sound like Amazon Prime?) my recent Memoirs of the AMS volume, "Modular Representation Theory and Commutative Banach Algebras" that takes similar ideas quite a lot further. I don't think it answers your question, but I'm not sure your question really has a non-trivial answer in the way you're expecting.

On the other hand, for the symmetric groups there is a nice duality of the sort you're looking for, between the "trivial source with Young vertex" indecomposables and the irreducible polynomial functors. Gordon James wrote a paper about this, but some day I should write something about the way I think of it.

@DaveBenson Thank you very much for the comments! I'll look into the papers you mentioned.
